# Автоустановка расширения для google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Как установить расширение в браузер хром программным путем. Запуск файла на компе->расширение добавлено в хром

Как это реализовать, какой файл в хроме отвечает за управление установленными расширениями?

Создал файл `nojpnepbplnoojhiinbpegidccgolald.json`(в качестве имени использовал id приложения, его получил установив плагин к себе в Google Chrome и скопировав его id) в папке `C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\31.0.1650.63\Extensions` со следующим содержанием:

```
{
"external_crx": "C:\Sdsattings.crx",

"external_version": "1.0"
}
```

crx файл разместил на диске `C`, перезапускаю Google Chrome и ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может это поможет [Предварительная установка с помощью файла master_preferences](https://support.google.com/a/answer/188453?hl=ru)